# How much more time are you going to stay online?

Tags: prepositions, questions, time

So today I was chatting with an oversees friend of mine and I asked him:

> How much more time are you going to stay online?

Just after asking, it seemed to me that it is not quite a natural structure. So I want to clear the doubt.

Is this construction correct? Is "much more" conveying the sense I want to? Or it sounds stilted?

Comment: It is grammatically not wrong, but you would rather use "How much longer are you going to stay online?"

Comment: Where did you get this quote from? Can you cite it please? ([see meta post here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please))

Comment: @Matt, It is from my personal usage. I was chatting with a friend in Facebook and that's where I asked it this way. I will rather add this part to my question.

Comment: Or, **"How much longer will you be online?"**

Comment: It is not grammatical because "more time" is not a comparative phrase. "Longer" is.

Comment: @RoaringFish, You mean to say `Have you got more time to chat with me?` is ungrammatical?

Comment: @Mistu4u I'd go with "Have you got ***any*** more time to chat with me?"

Comment: @WendiKidd, Okay, agreed. But unlike Roaring Fish mentioned, `more time` seems to be a comparative phrase.

Comment: @Mistu4u~ think about when the clock starts. With 'longer' the clock started when you went online, and you are asking how much time in comparison with the time until now. This matches the sense of 'stay'. With 'how much more time' the clock starts at the time of utterance so it carries a sense of reset that clashes with 'stay'.

Answer (score 1):

Just for a bit of variety, I'm going to suggest the sentence IS grammatical.

I'm not as expert in the exact parsing of sentences as other people here, however it appears to me that the sentence passes all the basic tests of grammar. The most important test is 'can it be easily and unambiguously comprehended by anybody'. I believe the answer is undoubtedly 'yes'.

As a native speaker, would I use those exact words? Perhaps not. My 'gut feeling', is that I would have said 'How much longer ...', but that seems very idiomatic to me, and less logical and clear when analysed than the sentence you actually used. The question refers to quantities of time, so why not actually say so?

That's an admittedly messy answer, but I think one has to accept that good written English is not always a matter black and white rules.

Comment: It's true, it's not always black and white.  Native speakers differ on which sentences they judge to be acceptable.  I wonder, if we took a random sampling, what people would say about this one?

Comment: Re: "[...] all the basic tests of grammar. The most important test is 'can it be easily and unambiguously comprehended by anybody'": If you're saying that this is the most important test of grammaticality, then -- I totally disagree. Something can be completely ungrammatical, yet easily understood (e.g. "You wants eat lunch now?"), and conversely, something can be perfectly grammatical, yet either confusing (e.g. "I haven't heard anyone disagree with *none* of the points") or ambiguous (e.g. "I like it better than you").

Comment: @ruakh I agree. I could have worded what I said better, and I pretty much thought I'd get a comment like yours when I posted it. "Can it be easily and unambiguously comprehended"' is not a test of grammar at all, but a test of communicability. A sentence's first objective is to be understood; it is far more likely to be understood if it is also grammatically correct.

Comment: @snailboat Yes, I was trying to avoid what I've seen a lot around here, namely "Sentence X sounds wrong to me as a native speaker". Clearly that's neither relevant nor helpful. However, I can make a judgement of 'would I have said it?'. For a non-native speaker I can see that "how much more time" is less ambiguous than the idiomatic "how much longer".

Comment: I think "Sentence X sounds wrong to me as a native speaker" is both relevant and helpful; I'm not sure why you say it's clearly not, and I don't really understand what you're proposing instead.

Comment: @ruakh. "Sentence X sounds wrong to me as a native speaker" is usually a reply to the question "Is sentence X grammatical?" As we have established, "sounding right" doesn't tell us anything about grammaticality, and therefore it is not relevant or helpful to the question.

On the other hand, it would be a fair response to the question "Would a native speaker say sentence X?"

Comment: Re: "As we have established, 'sounding right' doesn't tell us anything about grammaticality": Sure it does. I'm not sure who "we" is, but you can count me in the opposite camp. ;-)

Comment: "Something can be completely ungrammatical, yet easily understood ..., and conversely, something can be perfectly grammatical, yet ... confusing".

Comment: Wait, so because grammaticality is distinct from understandibility, you conclude that native speakers can't discern the former? I think that's a *non sequitur*.

Comment: Urgh. No, I conclude no such thing, and was making no such argument. All I was saying was (as you yourself argued) that "something does not sound right" does not answer the question "is something grammatical." Clearly native speakers can judge whether something is grammatical, otherwise I would not be on this website. However, all this is off topic to the OP's question.

Comment: I certainly did not argue what you're claiming I did; and you say that you're not making the argument that it sounds to me like you're making. But you seem to be implying that it's not worth clarifying, and I think I agree with that; we'll just have to agree to not be understanding each other. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This one gave me pause, but I don't think this question is grammatical.

Consider how this question would be answered:

> — How much more time are you going to stay online?
>   — I am going to stay online **for** ten more minutes.

The time is not a direct complement of the verb *stay*, it requires a preposition.

> For how much time are you going to stay online?

Contrast with a verb that doesn't take a preposition:

> — How much more time are you going to spend online?
>   — I am going to spend ten more minutes online.

If you use “how much longer” instead of “how much more time”, then you don't need the preposition, because *longer* works on its own as an indication of time.

> — How much longer are you going to stay online?
>   — I am going to stay online just a little longer.

“How much longer are you going to stay online?” is the idiomatic way of phrasing this question.

Comment: Why does needing a preposition in the answer mean the question is wrong? That argument even kills your own suggested correction:- "How much longer are you going to stay online?" ~~ "For twenty more minutes"

Comment: Suppose, I want to know specifically `how many more minutes`, then?

Comment: @RoaringFish The complement needs its preposition, whether the sentence is a question or not. Using *longer* or using a time amount is not the same thing: *stay online for twenty minutes* vs. *stay online longer*.

Comment: @Mistu4u Same thing: “How many more minutes are you going to stay online for?”

Comment: @Gilles~ exactly. The use of a preposition in the answer is unconnected with the question, which is why i am questioning your "consider how this question would be answered"

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong; "I'm going to stay online ten more minutes" is absolutely correct. (It's using "ten more minutes" as an *adjunct*.) Granted, it would *also* be correct to say "for ten more minutes", but that alternative is irrelevant to the OP's question.